# Linked List User Input

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

I am trying to make a linked list which will take input from user that how many number he wants to make the linked list not using the built in LinkedList function. but if the user input a negative number it will give message the user to input a positive number. I have done the code for user input but finding very difficulty for other parts-negative input and linking the numbers.can anyone please give me these parts of codes.

```
 import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

    class MyList{
    public MyList firstLink,lastLink;
    int info,size;
    MyList link;
    private MyList next;

    MyList(){
        this.link=null;
        firstLink = null;
        lastLink=null;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty(){
         return(firstLink == null);
     }

     public void showMyList() {
         MyList currentLink = firstLink;
            System.out.print("List: ");
            while(currentLink != null) {
                currentLink.showMyList();
                currentLink = currentLink.lastLink;
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
}

    public class MyLinkedList {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        MyList newMyList=new MyList();
        Scanner userInput= new Scanner(System.in);

        int userInputNumber;
        System.out.println("Enter Total Data");
        userInputNumber = userInput.nextInt();
            int i=1;
            while(i<=userInputNumber){
            System.out.println("Enter Data "+ i +":");
            i++; 
            newMyList.info=userInput.nextInt();
            }
            if(newMyList.firstLink!=null){
                newMyList=newMyList.firstLink;
                newMyList=newMyList.lastLink;
                newMyList.firstLink=newMyList.firstLink.link;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (userInputNumber < 0)`? Also i might check how the native implementation of a `LinkedList` does work. there no chance for you to iterate through it,

Comment: Can you give me the code for this and linking the numbers? It will be very helpful for me.

Comment: Your class MyList isn't implementation of Linked List structure. Now you have list of lists of lists...

Comment: here I want to make linked list of input numbers given by user. for example a use wants to make a singly linked list of 10  positive number. but if he gives any negative number it will warn the user to input positive number. I am unable to create linking between numbers or making the linked list.

Comment: can you give me proper solution @VladimirParfenov

Comment: @Prem First, you need to learn linked lists as data structures in theory. You can read Sedgewick's or Lafore's books about data structures and algorithms in java.

Answer (score 0):

This could help you understand Linked Lists:
[LinkedList in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)

A LinkedList consists of Nodes. A node could look like this:

```
class Node {
  Node previousNode, nextNode;
  int value;

  public Node getLastNode() {
    // traverse nextNode till it is null.. return the Node before.
  }
}
```

Make a method for reading the user input, which returns the number entered.

```
private int getUserInput() {
  int result = -1;
  Scanner userInput= new Scanner(System.in);
  while ( result < 0) {
    result = userInput.nextInt();
  }
  return result;
}
```

After that you can create your LinkedList by creating Nodes as much as needed.

```
Node myLinkedList = new Node();
myLinkedList.value = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < getUserInputResult; i++) {
  var newNode = new Node();
  newNode.value = i;
  // concat new Node to last Node in List;
  var lastNodeInList = myLinkedList.getLastNode();
  lastNodeInList .NextNode = newNode;
  newNode.previousNode = lastNodeInList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mixing the notion of list with the notion of node: a list can have a size, a first node and a last node, and a node only has an info, and a next node:

```
class MyList{
    private Node firstLink,lastLink;
    private int size;

    private static class Node {
        private int info;
        private Node next;
    }

    MyList(){
        this.link=null;
        firstLink = null;
        lastLink=null;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return(firstLink == null);
    }

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    public void add(int info) {
        Node node = new Node();
        node.info = info;
        if (firstLink == null) {
            firstLink = lastLink = node;
        } else {
            node.next = lastLink;
            lastLink = node;
        }
        ++size;
    }

    public void showMyList() {
        Node currentLink = firstLink;
        System.out.print("List: ");
        while (currentLink != null) {
            System.out.println(currentLink.info);
            currentLink = currentLink.next;
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```